# CSS/CSS3 filter content, why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot undestand why it is not working.

Basically, the idea is when you select an option it only shows the pictures related to it while the other pictures are slightly hidden.

It works perfectly if you move all the inputs inside the div called "gallery" but for designing reasons I need all the input radios in another separate div.

How could I solve it please?

NOTE: I have tried to make it using JS but I didn't have luck

Thanks

```css
/*Select Categorie*/

input#select-animals:checked~#gallery div:not(.animals-item),
input#select-lightning:checked~#gallery div:not(.lightning-item),
input#select-desert:checked~#gallery div:not(.desert-item) {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<h2>test</h2>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="select-all" name="button">
  <label for="select-all" class="label-all">
    All
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="select-animals" name="button">
  <label for="select-animals" class="label-animals">
    Animals
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="select-lightning" name="button">
  <label for="select-lightning" class="label-lightning">
    Lightning
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="select-desert" name="button">
  <label for="select-desert" class="label-desert">
    Desert
  </label>
</div>



<div class="gallery">
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7254/7740405218_deedfa35cb_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4086/4964465857_0bdbe1a84c_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5114/5858971312_0fec4bdaa0_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7338/12111748274_e3319bfbd5_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6206/6105317674_80f67a9a5e_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6143/5951696095_c6dd89f5da_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3130/2840585154_232b19bfbd_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8239/8548052436_a36e792c85_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/129/390350345_a0a04a139d_t.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `~` combinator only works for elements that share a common (immediate) parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general siblings selector `~` to work, you need to move the `input`'s outside their `div`, so they become *siblings* with the elements you want to target.

*I also changed the id selector `#` for the `gallery` rules, to class selector `.`*

```css
/*Select Categorie*/
input {
  display: none;
}
.labels {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.labels label:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#select-animals:checked ~ .gallery div:not(.animals-item),
#select-lightning:checked ~ .gallery div:not(.lightning-item),
#select-desert:checked ~ .gallery div:not(.desert-item) {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<h2>test</h2>

<input type="radio" id="select-all" name="button">
<input type="radio" id="select-animals" name="button">
<input type="radio" id="select-lightning" name="button">
<input type="radio" id="select-desert" name="button">

<div class="labels">
  <label for="select-all" class="label-all">
    All
  </label>
  <label for="select-animals" class="label-animals">
    Animals
  </label>
  <label for="select-lightning" class="label-lightning">
    Lightning
  </label>
  <label for="select-desert" class="label-desert">
    Desert
  </label>
</div>



<div class="gallery">
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7254/7740405218_deedfa35cb_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4086/4964465857_0bdbe1a84c_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5114/5858971312_0fec4bdaa0_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7338/12111748274_e3319bfbd5_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6206/6105317674_80f67a9a5e_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="desert-item">
    <img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6143/5951696095_c6dd89f5da_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3130/2840585154_232b19bfbd_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="animals-item">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8239/8548052436_a36e792c85_t.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="lightning-item">
    <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/129/390350345_a0a04a139d_t.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```